# Unable to locate package deb-multimedia-keyring

Tags: docker, ffmpeg

Hi I am trying to install the **FFMEPG** though the dockerfile.
I'm following the instructions mentioned [here][1]

But I'm getting the error like

> E: Unable to locate package deb-multimedia-keyring

> Failed to deploy ' Dockerfile: deploy/docker/serviceclient/Dockerfile': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream

**dockker file**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-bullseye
COPY ./ffmpeg-4.1.1.tar.bz2 /tmp
RUN     apt-get update -oAcquire::AllowInsecureRepositories=true &&  \
        apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends ca-certificates expat libgomp1  &&  \
        apt-get install deb-multimedia-keyring && \
        apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && \
        buildDeps= "build-essential libmp3lame-dev libvorbis-dev libtheora-dev && libspeex-dev yasm pkg-config libfaac-dev libopenjpeg-dev libx264-dev" && \
        apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends ${buildDeps} &&  \
        DIR=/home/sigadmin/bin/ffmpeg && mkdir -p ${DIR} && cd ${DIR} &&  \
    tar -jx --strip-components=1 -f /tmp/ffmpeg-4.1.1.tar.bz2 && \
        ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame &&  \
        --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree &&  \
        make && make install
```

Please help here to solve the problem.
[1]: https://support.assetbank.co.uk/hc/en-gb/articles/115005343247-Installing-Ffmpeg-on-Debian-GNU-Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, I installed the FFMPEG with command line with the default configuration. After the installation, I have checked the enabled configuration, seems that by default it enabled all my required configuration.

Commands I used :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

To install:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Verify the Installation

```
ffmpeg -version
```

[image]